# Hide specific parent categories from post edit

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have many custom post types and they all take advantage of wordpress categories. I therefore have several parent categories for each custom post type. Is there a way to hide the other parent categories when editing a certain custom post type?

In this screenshot for example I'd only like "Download Categories" to show while I'm in my custom post type "downloads".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're making a wrong use of taxonomies. Instead of using only the *Categories* taxonomy, you should create several [**Custom Taxonomies**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies).

I mean *Blog Categories*, *Download Categories*, *Team Departments*, etc... should be different taxonomies, and you should assing each of these taxonomies to the custom post type(s) they're related to...

Check the function [**register_taxonomy()**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for further information.

This is a very simple example:

```
function register_download_category() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'downloadcategory',
        'downloads',
        array(
            'label' => 'Download Categories',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'downloadcategory' ),
        )
     );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_download_category' );
```

In order to make queries by custom taxonomies you have to use the [**WP_Query Taxonomy Parameters**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: You are correct I should be using that. When I use 'category_name' in get_posts shall I replace this with 'tax_query' to be able to search for posts in a particular custom taxonomy?

Comment: @GreenGiant, yes exactly, you can use `tax_query` or I guess you can directly use `'downloadcategory' => 'payroll'` for example. See the link I added at the end of the answer for further info...

Comment: Ah yer 'customtax' => 'catslug' works too, much cleaner than an array with tax_query. Thank you so much!